# why doesn't this Python dictionary comprehension work for counting words in an input()?

Tags: python

I have to count the how many times a word is used in a sentence. I have found the solution, however i want the code to be more concise and want to solve it using dictionary comprehension. Can someone please help me understand what is wrong with the following code?

```
user_input = input().lower().split()
usage_dict = dict()
usage_dict = {word:usage_dict.get(word, 0) + 1 for word in user_input}
print(usage_dict)
```

Input : `a aa abC aa ac abc bcd a`

Output : `{'a': 1, 'aa': 1, 'abc': 1, 'ac': 1, 'bcd': 1}`

Expected Output: `{'a': 2, 'aa': 2, 'abc': 2, 'ac': 1, 'bcd': 1}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

The `usage_dict` dictionnary is created **once** the dict-comprehension is ended, there is no concept of temporary state of the dict, so `usage_dict.get(word, 0)` **always** gives 0

That is working only in a for loop:

```
usage_dict = {}
for word in user_input:
    usage_dict[word] = usage_dict.get(word, 0) + 1
```

---

#### Solutions

Use `list.count()`

```
usage_dict = {word: user_input.count(word) for word in set(user_input)}
```

Use `collections.Counter` which uses [the same for loop that above](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L511)

```
usage_dict = Counter(user_input)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware, dictionary doesn't get updated with every iteration in dict-comprehension. Now I know! @azro

Comment: @RahulDeshmukh that is same for list-comprehension

Comment: @RahulDeshmukh You can think about accepting the answer, if it satisfies you ;)

Comment: Yup stackoverflow asked me to wait 3 more minutes to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

user_input = input().lower().split()
usage_dict = Counter(user_input)
print(usage_dict)
```

Or:

```
usage_dict = {x:user_input.count(x) for x in user_input}
```

Returns

```
{'a': 2, 'aa': 2, 'abc': 2, 'ac': 1, 'bcd': 1}
```

Comment: I'd say that an answer, should .. **answer** to the question. which is here "what is wrong with the following code?" And you don't ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
user_input = input().lower().split()
usage_dict = {word: user_input.count(word) for word in user_input}
print(usage_dict)
```

Or use `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections
user_input = input().lower().split()
usage_dict = collections.Counter(user_input)
print(usage_dict)
```

Both codes output:

```
{'a': 2, 'aa': 2, 'abc': 2, 'ac': 1, 'bcd': 1}
```

The reason it doesn't work is because getting the count of value in the middle of a dictionary comprehension doesn't work, because it has to first finish the dictionary comprehension ***then*** assign it as a variable named `usage_dict`.

Comment: I'd say that an answer, should .. **answer** to the question. which is here "what is wrong with the following code?" And you don't ;)

Comment: @azro Edited my answer with the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Use Counter. See below

```
from collections import Counter

data = 'a aa abC aa ac abc bcd a'.split()
c = Counter(data)
print(c)
```

output

```
Counter({'a': 2, 'aa': 2, 'abC': 1, 'ac': 1, 'abc': 1, 'bcd': 1})
```

Comment: I'd say that an answer, should .. **answer** to the question. which is here "what is wrong with the following code?" And you don't ;)